# PHP extension is not recognised on Windows (using PHP 7.4)

Tags: php, events, pecl

I need the Event library for my project in PHP. The main project is running on a raspberry pi but I'm writing and testing the code completely on my Windows PC. To run the PHP code, I use the XAMPP.

I tried to import the Event extension within my code but in the command window, I keep getting the same error:

```
D:\xamd server\php>php.exe -i
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'event' (tried: D:\xamd server\php\ext\event (The specified module could not be found.), D:\xamd server\php\ext\php_event.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0
Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'event' (tried: D:\xamd server\php\ext\event (The specified module could not be found.), D:\xamd server\php\ext\php_event.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0
phpinfo()
PHP Version => 7.4.12
```

This error is weird in my opinion since the file which it can't fine on this link, should be there:

[image: "Proof" that the file is indeed in the correct folder]

I also added this file in some different folders such as system32 and apache\bin but none of this helps.
I downloaded the extension: "7.4 Thread Safe (TS) x64" from: https://pecl.php.net/package/event/3.0.7RC1/windows which should be the correct one for my PHP version.

And I also edited the php.ini file to add this extension to the library.

I'm probably forgetting one step but I have no idea what.
Would be great if someone could help me with this one.

Comment: The PHP extension is an interface to the actual code that does the business. Did you also install LibEvent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same error is displayed if the extension DLL was compiled for a different version of PHP.

Using Windows Explorer, right-click on the DLL and select properties, then Details. Check the **Product version** value.

The actual issue is that PHP extensions have an API version such as **20200930**. The API version must match PHP and the extension. The CLI command **php -i | grep API** will display this information.